# Half-open intervals

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding half-open intervals. 
When I'm supposed to calculate P(X ∈ ]-1,4]), when the probability is evenly distributed in the interval ]-2, 5], do I calculate the probability without taking account for the -1 probability, or do I leave out the 0 probability for some reason. 
The result is supposed to be 5/8, and I can only get that by leaving out one of the probabilities?

Comment: I get a probability of $5/7$.

Comment: That might be correct too, but how do you get that? Do you leave one of the probabilities out?

Comment: if the probability in the interval ]-2,5] is 1/7, then in ]-1,4] it is 5/7, but then that means that you leave out the -2 and -1 probabilties, right? Because they're in the open part of the interval?

Comment: A single point contributes nothing to the length of the interval.  The length of $]-1, 4]$ is $5$ and the length of $]-2, 5]$ is $7$.